Unity Editor will consistently freeze every 5-8 seconds for up to 5 seconds
I've been working on a project on my laptop for a few weeks now and occasionally (seemingly randomly) I will launch Unity and the Editor will undergo this strange pattern of consistent freezes. It freezes in both editing and play modes, and as you can probably assume it's very irritating!
Restarting does not fix it, restarting Unity does not fix it, I've updated drivers, disabled antivirus, regenerated project files, re-installed Unity and closed background processes.
Looking at the Unity profiler the freeze coincides with a massive spike in usage in the "Others" category, but using task manager Unity is barely using half of my RAM and around 20% of my CPU. Furthermore, when I open the same project on a home PC it hasn't ever done this. Sometimes I'll be working and it's fine on my laptop, but while I have Unity open it will suddenly start the pattern again!
Does anyone have any ideas? Any help at all is greatly appreciated!
Processor: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1255U 1.70 GHz
RAM: 16.0 GB (15.7 GB usable, 8.8 GB used by Unity pretty consistently)
If any more information is needed let me know.
Edit: On further research I've looked through the editor logs and they are very long and hard to read haha, but there seems to be a repeated "scanning for USB devices" for 4000ms to 6000ms that might be causing the freezes. Does anyone know how to stop this?

sounds more like my old laptop where it was resetting the disk every whatever..   did you check event log?

Thanks for trying to help, I have not checked those, where are they found or how can I access them on a windows machine?

Id say its concerning you dont know how to find the eventlog of your machine, in short run eventviewer
